# ContextMenu using Right Click button

Tags: javascript, dom-events, contextmenu

I need to create a `ContextMenu` that will only show when you right click on a label. `MenuManager` is where I have the list of menu on my context menu and it is on another file so what I did is initialize the `MenuManager`.

`.MyLayerEdit.Add` is the Element I created. I'm not really sure if I did the right `ContextMenu` function, I just copied this from the other files.

```
//**initialization of class MyLayerEdit    
var MyLayerManager = new MyLayerEdit();
var menuManager = MenuManager.MyLayerEdit.Add;

//***Creating a class 'MyLayerEdit'
    var MyLayerEdit = Class.create(){
    MyLayerEdit.prototype {
    initialize : function () {
    this.define();
  },

//**Creating ContextMenu  
 var ContextMenu = Class.create()
    ContextMenu.prototype(element, layerNo, layerName {
        this.define(element, layerNo, layerName)
},

    function MyLayer(){

    this.conMenu = new ContextMenu(this); 
    this.conMenu.call(this.conMenu, menuManager);
//***errorhandler callback 
  var errorHandler = function(callback){
    KKC.Error.checkError(msg, ex) 
    }
},
```

Now I don't know what the next thing to do to show the context menu. Anyone know how to create a simple context menu? Using right click button?

On my Specs, its says Create a Class

```
var MyLayerEdit = Class.create()
```

and then define is as:

```
var MyLayerManager = new MyLayerEdit()
```

before I initialize `MyLayerEdit` to the other file and call the error method where I did.
I made an element `MyLayerEdit` under `MenuManager` in the other file.
Next is to call the show method of context menu to display it, i need to create the context menu:

```
var ContextMenu = Class.create()
```

Comment: Attach a handler to the contextmenu event or the label element.  If you cancel the event the normal menu will not appear.  In your handler, position and show your context menu elements.  If you can produce a sample ( like jsFiddle ) then it will be easier to guide the solution

Comment: @RobertSlaney Thanks, Will try to do that and I'm going to try to produce a jsFiddle sample, I'm new to Javascript so I'm really having a hard time as I do research one by one on how to create a class and stuff.